# Delphi: EInvalidOp in neural network class (TD-lambda)

Tags: delphi, exception, neural-network, pascal, temporal-difference

I have the following draft for a neural network class. This neural network should learn with TD-lambda. It is started by calling the getRating() function.

But unfortunately, there is an EInvalidOp (invalid floading point operation) error after about 1000 iterations in the following lines:

```
neuronsHidden[j] := neuronsHidden[j]+neuronsInput[t][i]*weightsInput[i][j]; // input -> hidden

weightsHidden[j][k] := weightsHidden[j][k]+LEARNING_RATE_HIDDEN*tdError[k]*eligibilityTraceOutput[j][k]; // adjust hidden->output weights according to TD-lambda
```

Why is this error? I can't find the mistake in my code :( Can you help me? Thank you very much in advance!

```
learningMode: Boolean; // does the network learn and change its weights?
neuronsInput: Array[1..MAX_TIMESTEPS] of Array[1..NEURONS_INPUT] of Extended;
neuronsHidden: Array[1..NEURONS_HIDDEN] of Extended;
neuronsOutput: Array[1..NEURONS_OUTPUT] of Extended;
weightsInput: Array[1..NEURONS_INPUT] of Array[1..NEURONS_HIDDEN] of Extended;
weightsHidden: Array[1..NEURONS_HIDDEN] of Array[1..NEURONS_OUTPUT] of Extended;

[...]

function HyperbolicTangent;
begin
  if x > 5500 then // prevent overflow
    result := 1
  else
    result := (Exp(2*x)-1)/(Exp(2*x)+1);
end;
[...]
```

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, I am, definitely. But since I've replaced the Extended variables by Real variables, there's no error anymore. I don't know if this is just a coincidence. Why should this solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for you error is that you are overflowing the accumulators `neuronsHidden` or `weightsHidden`. I know nothing about neural networks so I can't offer any explanation as to why this is so.

As a side issue, I question the use of `Extended` floating point variables. Normally this simply results in extremely slow performance, much slower than when using `Double`. You may think it gives you more headroom for large numbers, but in reality, if this is a run-away overflow of the nature that I suspect, then using `Extended` would never save you.

**UPDATE** OP points out that overflow results in a different exception class. So for `EInvalidOp` I suspect some square root or trig failure or something like that. Or perhaps a signaling NaN, but since you don't obviously use uninitialised data I'll not persue that.

I can see now that you have been affected by Embarcadero's bizarre decision to break their implementation of `Tanh`. This used to work perfectly on older versions of Delphi (e.g. D6), but was broken recently.  The version you use isn't quite right for large negative input, and uses two calls to `Exp` when one suffices.  I use this version:

```
const
  MaxTanhDomain = 5678.22249441322; // Ln(MaxExtended)/2

function Tanh(const X: Extended): Extended;
begin
  if X>MaxTanhDomain then begin
    Result := 1.0
  end else if X<-MaxTanhDomain then begin
    Result := -1.0
  end else begin
    Result := Exp(X);
    Result := Result*Result;
    Result := (Result-1.0)/(Result+1.0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If I was overflowing the accumulators neuronsHidden or weightsHidden, there would be an EOverflow error, wouldn't it? But now I replaced all Extended variables by Real variables (= Double) in my code.

Comment: Sorry, yes that would be an EOverflow. If you were doing `Sqrt` or trig then you might see `EInvalidOp`, but you aren't are you. You also get `EInvalidOp` for signaling NaNs. What you need to do is to break at the point of the error and see what values are being used. Find a reproduction of the fault and a way to break at the point at which it fails. Or just spew the values out to the debug window with `OutputDebugString`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the improvement of my tanh() function. It works perfectly :) Are you sure that Delphi's built-in tanh() function is broken?

Comment: @user yes it's catastrophically broken. It throws exceptions for large magnitude values. It's slow the rest of the time. My alternative comes from delphi 6 rtl so they changed it to make it worse! Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @user There's a report of this bug in QC (the public bug reporting tool used by Embarcadero) but even though they knew it was wrong way back in 2008 they haven't been able to fix it. It is very frustrating that they offer a tool for their users to debug their products but then fail to fix the product!

Comment: @user If your code is working now it's probably the change to using the fixed `tanh` rather than the change from `Extended` to `Real` that did the trick.

Comment: I've run some tests and you're right. So thank you very, very much David, your answer was very important and helpful for me. If you run Delphi's built-in tanh() function, there is an EOverflow error. If you run my HyperbolicTangent() function from above, there is the EInvalidOp error. And your version works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just a suggestion; The two lines of code you're showing only include multiplication and addition, very simple operations. How about logging the values on failure, maybe seeing the values you can figure something out.

The most annoying trouble with stopping on exception is that you can't inspect the variables involved in that exception. To work around that limitation I sometimes wrap the troublesome operation in an `try-except` block and place a breakpoint in the `except` handler; Delphi will first stop at the exception, I hit run, and then it stops on my breakpoint. At the breakpoint I can freely inspect all variables used in the error-generating statement, so I can figure out what's wrong.

```
// In place of:
neuronsHidden[j] := neuronsHidden[j]+neuronsInput[t][i]*weightsInput[i][j];

var saveNerusonsHidden: Double;
try
  saveNeuronsHidden := neuronsHidden[j]; // saved, to be sure I can inspect the original value
  neuronsHidden[j] := neuronsHidden[j]+neuronsInput[t][i]*weightsInput[i][j];
except on E:EInvalidOp do
  begin
    // Breakpoint here, so you can inspect the values of neuronsInput[t][i], wightsInput[i][j] and saveNeuronsHidden
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion :) What exactly does the "raise" do? Why do I need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get EInvalidOp when calculation very large or very small numbers.

When getting this error, maybe you can debug/view the values in the array and do a partial calculation in the watch list?

Comment: But for too large or too small numbers there is a special error type, namely EOverflow, isn't it?